# Xquery to parse XML tags into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have below piece of XML as part of XML column in table say MyTable

```
<policystatusdetail id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<CurrentUser>ABCDEFG</CurrentUser>
<LastModifiedDateTime>2016-04-02T17:03:01.761</LastModifiedDateTime>
<PolicyStatus>Quote-New-Pending</PolicyStatus>
</policystatusdetail>
```

I want to extract only PolicyStatus as column.

I am using below query

```
Select x.r.value('@PolicyStatus','varchar(500)') as PolicyStatus 
from 
(Select cast(XMLData as XML) XMLData from Mytable) s
cross apply s.XMLData.nodes('session/data/policyAdmin/policyStatusdetail') as x(r)
```

But it returns zero rows. Can anyone help?

Comment: It might be an issue with case. If your xml looks like `policystatusdetail`, you need to look for the node `policystatusdetail`, not `policyStatusdetail`. Also, `PolicyStatus[1]`, not `@PolicyStatus`. Using what you're currently using, it will look for the attribute "PolicyStatus" in the policystatusdetail node (e.g. to find "id", you'd use `@id`).

Comment: Hi Chaitanya, as you are quite new here (btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you* (you placed an answer for this), but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 DECLARE @xml XML='<policystatusdetail id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                     <CurrentUser>ABCDEFG</CurrentUser>
                     <LastModifiedDateTime>2016-04-02T17:03:01.761</LastModifiedDateTime>
                     <PolicyStatus>Quote-New-Pending</PolicyStatus>
                     </policystatusdetail><policystatusdetail id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
                     <CurrentUser>ABCDEFG</CurrentUser>
                     <LastModifiedDateTime>2016-04-02T17:03:01.761</LastModifiedDateTime>
                     <PolicyStatus>Quote-New-Pending</PolicyStatus>
                     </policystatusdetail>'

   --Method 1.SELECT  s.b.value('PolicyStatus[1]','varchar(500)') FROM @xml.nodes('policystatusdetail') s(b)
   --Method 2.
   SELECT  s.b.value('.','varchar(500)') FROM @xml.nodes('policystatusdetail/PolicyStatus') s(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several flaws:

- XML is strictly **case-sensitive**. Your `/policyStatusdetail` **cannot** find `<policystatusdetail>`
- Your own query shows, that there must be more: `.nodes('session/data/policyAdmin/policyStatusdetail')`
- The `CAST` you use (`Select cast(XMLData as XML)`) shows, that this XML is - probably - stored within a non-XML column. What is the actual data type?
- We cannot know, if there is only one occurance of this node. As the XML is bigger obviously there might be more of them?

If you really need nothing else than the first occurance of `<PolicyStatus>` this can be done very simply:

```
SELECT CAST(XMLData AS XML).value('(//PolicyStatus)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PolicyStatus
FROM Mytable
```

The `//` at the beginning will trigger a *deep search* and find the first element with the given name...